# Convert a string with curly brackets using python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, format

I have the following string:

```
{At condition {0}, the value of {1} must be between {2} and {3}.}{{code{min <= 100}}}{{code{min}}}{0}{100}
```

How to convert any similar string to the below format in python?

```
At condition `min <= 100`, the value of `min` must be between 0 and 100.
```

Numbers in curly brackets should be replaced by the corresponding values. If a value is wrapped into `{code{value}}`, dedicated symbols `` should be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright this is a little brittle/messy but it should work given the structure you provided.

```
def convert(s):
    # Find index  of first }{ as this is end of initial string
    idx = s.find('}{')
    initial = s[1:idx]
    # Everything after this index is an argument
    args = s[idx+2:-1]
    args = args.split('}{')
    # Iterate through args and subsitute into initial string
    for i, arg in enumerate(args):
        # Check to see if arg wrapped in {code{}}
        val_idx = arg.find('code{')
        if val_idx != -1:
            # Replace wrapped value with backticks
            arg = '`{}`'.format(arg[val_idx+5:-2])
        # Place arg into proper place in initial string
        initial = initial.replace('{{{}}}'.format(i), arg)

    return initial
```

Calling:

```
convert('{At condition {0}, the value of {1} must be between {2} and {3}.}{{code{min <= 100}}}{{code{min}}}{0}{100}')
convert('{{0} bar}{foo}')
```

Returns:

```
At condition `min <= 100`, the value of `min` must be between 0 and 100.
foo bar
```